# Calculator rounding to fit in editText

Tags: android, kotlin, rounding, calculator

I have an editText limited to 14 characters. This works to limit the number the user inputs but it just cuts off numbers bigger than 14 characters(even after the decimal) in the answer. So, two problems I need help with. How do I make it so that errors if the value is larger than 14 digits, and to always round to the best place(like if the sum is 164541254.4568727(17char), it will round to 164541254.4569(14char) or 12.9876543210987 rounds to 12.9876543211)

Equal button code(because I think this is where I'll need to put the code):

```
fun equal(view: View) {
    secondnum = editText.text.toString()
    decpressed = 0
    var sum = 0.0
    when (op) {
        "+" -> {
            sum = (firstnum.toDouble() + secondnum.toDouble())
        }
        "-" -> {
            sum = (firstnum.toDouble() - secondnum.toDouble())
        }
        "*" -> {
            sum = (firstnum.toDouble() * secondnum.toDouble())
        }
        "/" -> {
            if (secondnum == "0") {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Can not divide by 0!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                editText.setText("0")
                textView.text = ""
            } else {
                sum = (firstnum.toDouble() / secondnum.toDouble())
            }
        }
    }
    val out = DecimalFormat("#.##########")
    out.roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN
    editText.setText(out.format(sum))
    textView.text = "$firstnum $op $secondnum ="
    zero = true
}
```

If other code is needed, please request it.

Comment: Do you want to limit the number of decimal digits or the total length?

Comment: you should create a condition like trimming the sum first to 13 characters. then create a condition for the rest characters

Comment: @VSSChaitanyaChavali my decimal digits are limited with DecimalFormat.. but when the whole number is more than 1 digit it doesn't round the decimal number, it just chops off the end and same with non-decimal numbers.. if the number is more than 14 digits, it just chops off the end

Comment: @andika_kurniawan can you explain what you mean in an answer?